# Parsing double superCSV with comma as decimal separator?

Tags: supercsv

I Want to parse a double with comma as decimal separator (',' instead of '.') using SuperCSV CellProcessor

I want to parse the first element (0,35) to Double

```text
0,35;40000,45
```

I have tried something like that :

```java
   /** FRENCH_SYMBOLS */
private static final DecimalFormatSymbols FRENCH_SYMBOLS = new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.FRANCE);
  DecimalFormat   df =   new DecimalFormat();
  df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(FRENCH_SYMBOLS);
 final CellProcessor[] processors = new CellProcessor[] {
                new NotNull(new ParseDouble(new FmtNumber(df))),
                new NotNull(new ParseBigDecimal(FRENCH_SYMBOLS)) };
```

ParseBigDecimal works just fine but the parseDouble doesn't seems to work, it gives me an exception : org.supercsv.exception.SuperCsvCellProcessorException: '0,35' could not be parsed as a Double

Comment: Use quotes around the number, for example: "1,000","20,000",50,"test". Or do you mean that you want to use ";" as the delimeter. What do you want to convert the line to?

Comment: I want to parse that field 0,35 as a Double, it gives me an exception : org.supercsv.exception.SuperCsvCellProcessorException: '0,35' could not be parsed as a Double

Comment: We can create an all new class that implements DoubleCellProcessor with our own special needs 

http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_new_cell_processor.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're totally correct - `ParseDouble` doesn't support a French-style decimal separator (comma), but `ParseBigDecimal` does. If you think this is a useful feature, why not submit a [feature request](https://sourceforge.net/p/supercsv/feature-requests/).

The simplest workaround is to simply chain a [StrReplace](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html) before the `ParseDouble` to convert the comma to full stop.

```
new StrReplace(",", ".", new ParseDouble())
```

Alternatively, you could write a [custom cell processor](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_new_cell_processor.html) that either:

- parses a Double (with a configurable decimal separator)
- converts a BigDecimal to a Double (calling `doubleValue()`) - this can then be chained after your `new ParseBigDecimal(FRENCH_SYMBOLS)`

Oh, and in future you might want to mention that your file is semi-colon separated and you've set up Super CSV with `CsvPreference.EXCEL_NORTH_EUROPE_PREFERENCE` :)